# Where to define view-specific data objects in Rails

Tags: design, ruby-on-rails

Background: there are several places in our app where we want to display date-oriented information on a calendar. The [event_calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar) gem looks nice and has lots of reviews, so it's what I'm planning to use. However, it's designed to work with a model. I'm not going to update our existing models to meet its needs, so will create a DTO class and a helper function to construct an array of instances from our existing models.

My question is: where should that DTO class live? It seems like it should be defined inside `ViewHelper`, but that will violate DRY as soon as I use the calendar for two models (note: the helper functions will differ, it's just the DTO class that will remain the same).

So, is there a standard place in the Rails directory tree where non-model-related classes live?

Or is there a better/more idiomatic way to do this? One thought that I had was to make my helper function decorate the existing model instances with the methods that event_calendar wants to see.

Answer (score 2):

I think the equivalent of the Data Transfer Object you mention is called a presenter in the Rails ecosystem.

On projects with few presenters, I have seen them placed in the `/lib` directory, but you might as well create an `/app/presenters` directory.

Also check out [this blog post on presenters](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-09-09-better-ruby-presenters) by Steve Klabnik.

Comment: Not quite: as I read the blog post (+1 for that, btw), the presenter object is the thing that produces the DTO (this became more clear when I read his earlier post).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you would like to use repetitive non model functionality. If I am right, then you can wrap it with Module and put it within app\models folders

You might have a look at the following article
http://www.codercaste.com/2011/02/11/10-ruby-on-rails-3-tips-that-will-make-you-a-better-rails-programmer/

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a base class in `lib`, that defines the attributes and a few helper methods. I kept a class inside the helper, but all it has is an `initialize` (that's where the interesting stuff happens). I also have a helper function that does the `map` to convert objects.

Reading Steve Klabnik's blog, I came across the following quote, which I think summed up my feelings going into this. I think I've gotten over it.

> Maybe it's that lib/ feels like such a junk drawer

Answer (score 0):

If you find you are repeating yourself a lot, you might want to take a look at the [cells gem](https://github.com/apotonick/cells). Cells are basically mini-controllers that are especially useful when creating widgets and the like.

The readme sums it up nicely:

> Say you’re writing a Rails online shop - the shopping cart is
>   reappearing again and again in every view. You’re thinking about a
>   clean solution for that part. A mixture of controller code,
>   before-filters, partials and helpers?
>
> No. That sucks. Take Cells.